# android widget with multiple buttons

Tags: android, button, click, widget

i have developed a android widget with mutiple buttons on it. it works fine and i add first time. but when i reboot the device buttons do not fire. here it is what i do

here is xml config

```
<receiver android:name="com.islem.widget.MyWidgetMain" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will also process our self created action -->
    <action android:name="com.islem.widget.KalanWidgetMain.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER1"/>
    <action android:name="com.islem.widget.KalanWidgetMain.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER2"/>
    <action android:name="com.islem.widget.KalanWidgetMain.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER3"/>
    <action android:name="com.islem.widget.KalanWidgetMain.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER4"/>
    <action android:name="com.islem.widget.KalanWidgetMain.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER5"/>
    <action android:name="com.islem.widget.KalanWidgetMain.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER6"/>
    <action android:name="com.islem.widget.KalanWidgetMain.ACTION_WIDGET_RELOAD_ALARM"/>

</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/k_widget_provider" />
```

here is the onUpdate method

```
    @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {      

    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.kalan_widget_main);

        Intent refreshButtonIntent = new Intent(context, KalanWidgetMain.class);
        refreshButtonIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER1);

        Intent voiceTabIntent = new Intent(context, KalanWidgetMain.class);
        voiceTabIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER2);

        Intent dataTabIntent = new Intent(context, KalanWidgetMain.class);
        dataTabIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER3);

        Intent smsTabIntent = new Intent(context, KalanWidgetMain.class);
        smsTabIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER4);

        Intent prevButtonIntent = new Intent(context, KalanWidgetMain.class);
        prevButtonIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER5);

        Intent nextButtonIntent = new Intent(context, KalanWidgetMain.class);
        nextButtonIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER6);

        refreshButtonIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        voiceTabIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        dataTabIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        smsTabIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        prevButtonIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        nextButtonIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

        PendingIntent refreshButtonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, refreshButtonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent voiceTabPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, voiceTabIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent dataTabPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, dataTabIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent smsTabPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, smsTabIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent prevButtonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, prevButtonIntent, 0);
        PendingIntent nextButtonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, nextButtonIntent, 0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.kalanRefresh, refreshButtonPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.kalanTabVoiceBg, voiceTabPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.kalanTabDataBg, dataTabPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.kalanTabSMSBg, smsTabPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.kalanPrev, prevButtonPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.kalanNext, nextButtonPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

        KalanUpdater.registerWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId); 
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

here is the onReceive method

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    System.out.println("on onReceive");     
    Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // v1.5 fix that doesn't call onDelete Action
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
        final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
        }
    } else {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER1) || intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER2) ||
                intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER3) || intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER4) ||
                intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER5) || intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER6) ||
                intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RELOAD_ALARM) 
                ) {             
            int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            System.out.println("appWidgetId:" + appWidgetId + ", action:" + action);




        }


        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you uploaded your Widget somewhere i need to see it's code. if you can help it will really be helpful. I am new to Android and trying to build a widget.

Answer (score 0):

When phone restart, it will call `onEnable` instead of `onUpdate`.

--update--

```
int[] allids = AppWidgetManager
.getInstance(Context)
.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(Context, YourAppWidgetProvider.class);
```

This will get all ids that is under the control of YourAppWigetProvider. Read more on [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html)

Comment: i have moved content of onupdate into a method and calling from onEnabled and onUpdate like below but not works. and also i can see onUpdate log when reboot.
 @Override
 public void onEnabled(Context context) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onEnabled(context);
  Toast.makeText(context, "onEnabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
  int[] appWidgetIds = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, KalanWidgetMain.class));
  startWidget(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), appWidgetIds);
 }

Comment: do't remove from onUpdate  just copy in onEnabled